# GCC header file include bug?

Tags: c, gcc

I might be experiencing a gcc header include bug not im not too sure

If I compile my code, I get type not defined error like this

```
src/kernel/memory.h:102:31: error: unknown type name 'IDT_pageFault_error_t'
  102 | void memory_interrupt_handler(IDT_pageFault_error_t pageFault_error, uintptr_t cr2);
```

I am sure this is not related to circular inclusions as I guarded all header files with `#pragma once` so i'm not sure what is causing this include error

Code snippets (removed all the unrelated bits of code)

`interrupt.h`

```
#pragma once
#include "memory.h"

typedef struct IDT_pageFault_error_t {
    union {
        uint32_t data;
        struct {
            uint32_t P:1;                                                                       // Present              When set, the page fault was caused by a page-protection violation. When not set, it was caused by a non-present page.
            uint32_t W:1;                                                                       // Write                When set, the page fault was caused by a write access. When not set, it was caused by a read access.
            uint32_t U:1;                                                                       // User                 When set, the page fault was caused while CPL = 3. This does not necessarily mean that the page fault was a privilege violation.
            uint32_t R:1;                                                                       // Reserved write       When set, one or more page directory entries contain reserved bits which are set to 1. This only applies when the PSE or PAE flags in CR4 are set to 1.
            uint32_t reserved:28;
        } __attribute__ ((packed));
    };
} __attribute__ ((packed)) IDT_pageFault_error_t;
```

`memory.h`

```
#pragma once
#include "interrupt.h"

void memory_interrupt_handler(IDT_pageFault_error_t pageFault_error, uintptr_t cr2);
```

I've been rolling my head around this problem for hours but still can't find any answers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Using cycling inclusion of headers is generally a bad idea. And it IS a problem with cyclic inclusing. But not related to multiple inclusion.

Comment: That's odd! Is it possible you have another interrupt.h file that is found before the one that defines `IDT_pageFault_error_t`?

Comment: Why do you need to include `memory.h` inside `interrupt.h`?

Comment: So remove `#include "memory.h"` from `interrupt.h`

Comment: You cannot have two headers that include each other because that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @KamilCuk The reason I didn't remove `#include "memory.h"` from `interrupt.h` is because i used some functions from `interrupt.h`

But just tried it anyway, it compiled however now the compiler spits out warnings about implicit function declarations

Comment: So refactor the code - move stucture definition to a separate header, included form both headers that use it...

Comment: @Lundin The `#interrupt.c` and `memory.c` have functions and types that depend on each other.

Comment: Then your design is fundamentally flawed. Perhaps creating a 3rd module which resides on a higher layer than the 2 others is the solution?

Comment: @Lundin Yeah I guess you you're right. As someone coming from doing java and c#, these header files confuse the heck out of me

Comment: @피주원 Think of the h file as the class declaration and the c file as private implementation details.

Comment: H files should be fully analysable, so should `#include` any needed headers - it is thoroughly frustrating when you `#include` a file and get errors because of undefined items, so you have to guess what else to `#include`...  if there is a dependency, declare it!